# Articles only show up when users logged in

Tags: mediawiki

I administer a mediawiki and I've run into an issue which I have not been able to solve or find any information about anywhere. The problem is that new articles created on my wiki only show up for users which are logged in. If the users use the search, they can find them there but if they pull up lists of all in a category then they don't show up there. Nor do they show up in a semantic list. This is a problem as these articles are reports with are not easily searchable so we depend on the category page to find what we are looking for. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Aren't you using [FlaggedRevs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FlaggedRevs)?

Comment: All new articles are doing this or just ones created by anon / people without auto-patrol rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to run across this exact problem myself a couple of weeks ago. The solution turned out to be turning off the cache for the wiki. I was using the simple file cache for my site, but it started exhibiting the same problems you were having. I don't know how MediaWiki's caches work, but it seemed as though the cache was serving out-of-date data to users who weren't logged in (note how caching is only performed for certain users and pages as explained [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aFile_cache#Domain_and_range)). Refreshing pages and changing their contents didn't seem to help, nor did manually editing pages' category links in the database.

In my case, the fix was to change

```
$wgUseFileCache = true;
```

to

```
$wgUseFileCache = false;
```

I would have preferred to keep the cache up for the speed improvements (and if I figure out exactly what happened, I will), but I would rather have the user see the correct content instead.

Obviously, if you're using a different cache system, the method to turn off the cache will be different. If the problem is not the cache, then I'm not sure what it could be, although by turning it off temporarily you will at least have eliminated one variable and made it easier to figure out the underlying issue.